# Get field value of sub site in wordpress by ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

We have a `Wordpress` website which has 10 sub sites(blogs) . We show the latest post of those sub sites on the main site . Recently we added and use [Advanced Custom Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which is active now on the main site and all those 10 sub sites and in each one we sat just a true/false  field and its name is  : `is_announce` . 
In each site ( main or sub sites ) we have access to that field by `get_field` and it works great .
The problem is , on the main site we have no access to those fields of sub sites.It seems `get_field` works good just for each site's scope ( main or sub sites )

How can we fix it ?

Addition : As i told you we show the latest post of each sub website . each one has been featured by one custom field (`is_announce`) . We want to read its value and if it is `True` , show something on the top of each post , something like tag .

Comment: You will probably need to use the `switch to blog` function

Comment: Thank you so much for help . It was really helpful :)   i will post my codes .

Answer (score 1):

Based on RST's comment , i could solve my problem :

```
                <?php

                        $slug = $post->blogname;
                        $blog_id = get_id_from_blogname($slug);

                        switch_to_blog($blog_id);

                        if( get_field('is_announce') )
                        {
                            echo "<div class='announce-container'>ANNOUNCE</div>";
                        }

                        restore_current_blog();

                ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code example. Glad you got it to work.

Comment: @RST  I put this block of code inside a foreach loop . it works on first record but not for the rest . Do you think  it is because of restore_current_blog  or something else ?

Comment: probably restoring current blog too soon?

Comment: @RST  It was something wrong with data entry . Thanks again for help :)

Comment: Beware with those blog switching. I had a weird bug with yoast seo not saving fields like mention here: https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/6121